# Problem with synchornizing time and animations in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My problem is that I want to play different animations basing on the time left for the user to guess. My current code doesn't work, because of the nature of the Unity Update. Not sure how to change it. Don't want to turn it into Coroutine, because I would have to change a lot of previous code. Will be extremely grateful for the help.

```c#
if(userGuessing)
{
    timerText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = timer.ToString("0.00");
    Debug.Log(timer);
}

if(timer > 90)
{
    bossArmature.animation.Play("BossVeryHappy", -1);
}
else if(timer > 70 && timer < 90)
{
    bossArmature.animation.Play("BossHappy", -1);
}
else if(timer > 50 && timer < 70)
{
    bossArmature.animation.Play("BossNeutral", -1);
}
else if(timer > 30 && timer < 50)
{
    bossArmature.animation.Play("BossAngry", -1);
}
```

Comment: Why not make the animator do all the work and just set timer to a value in animator and have it play the appropriate animation depending on the value

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I'm not using animator. All the animations were made with Dragonbones Pro and I'm importing it as Armature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What BugFinder means was probably: Use [Animator Parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) and transitions as in [Tobenai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58875257/7111561) which I would prefer actually as it is way easier to maintain and extend. Unfortunately we don't really know if `bossArmature.animation` is really an `Animator` though it pretty much seems to be.

---

However, if you want to stick to your solution I would simply add an enum state

```c#
private enum BossState
{
    VeryHappy,
    Happy,
    Neutral,
    Angry
}
```

and have a field for storing such a value:

```c#
private BossState state;
```

and an according [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for automatically update the animator whenever the value is changed:

```c#
private BossState State
{
    get => state;
    set
    {
        state = value;
        switch(state)
        {
            case BossState.VeryHappy:
                bossArmature.animation.Play("BossVeryHappy", -1);
                break;
            case BossState.Happy:
                bossArmature.animation.Play("BossHappy", -1);
                break;
            case BossState.Neutral:
                bossArmature.animation.Play("BossNeutral", -1);
                break;
            case BossState.Angry:
                bossArmature.animation.Play("BossAngry", -1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and then change your Update method to only check the according cases if you are not already in that state, otherwise you always restart the animation every frame.

```c#
if(userGuessing){
    timerText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = timer.ToString("0.00");
    Debug.Log(timer);
}

if(State != BossState.VeryHappy && timer > 90)
{
    State = BossState.VeryHappy;
}
else if(State != BossState.Happy && timer > 70 && timer < 90)
{
    State = BossState.Happy;
}
else if(State != BossState.Neutral && timer > 50 && timer < 70)
{
    State = BossState.Neutral;
}
else if(State != BossState.Angry && timer < 50)
{
    State = BossState.Angry;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Wanted to say BIG THANK YOU for showing me this method. Thanks to it, I stared using enum more often and my code looks much more ordered now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use animator conditions to control the behaviour based on your timer, simply set the 'Timer' parameter of the Animator to the current timer value. Then use the LessThan condition to progress through the different animations.

```c#
bossArmature.animation.SetFloat("Timer", timer);
```

It could then look like this

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you but I made all the animations in Dragonbones Pro so, at least as far as I know, its the only way to start animations.

Comment: This would be also the way I would prefer, but it is assuming that `bossArmature.animation` is of type `Animator` which might not be the case (but we don't know since we don't see the types)

Comment: Yes, it's my bad that I didn't write that I use Dragonebones at the beggining. Unfortunately it doesn't have the animator.